# Why does this jQuery UI datepicker seem to be a noop if I try to change the format?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, date-format

I would like to have a Datepicker field that provides an ISO 8601 yyyy-mm-dd. I've done a little bit of research and have found other invocations that should specify an alternate format, but so far every dateFormat I've tried (should I be using altFormat?) results in a noop.

(If I click on the field after just calling jQuery().datepicker() with no arguments, it displays the datepicker, and submits with a format for the date that I don't want. However, if I call non-dictionary arguments, there is no logged error but it doesn't display the datepicker. I've tried:

```
1:  // jQuery('input#day').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
2:  // jQuery('input#day').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
3:  jQuery('input#day').datepicker();
4:  // jQuery('input#day').datepicker({'dateFormat': 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

3 is what I have now, and it works modulo submitting a value matching /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/. (I don't know which is submitted as month, does it do the worst of submitting mm/dd/yyyy in one part of the world and dd/mm/yyyy in others?)

1 and 2 are the ones I've tried that seem to convert the datepicker() call into a noop; 4 displays a datepicker and appears to work, but when I submit it after picking a date, the submitted date is empty.

How can I get the result of using the datepicker to match yyyy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('input#day').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Will return a date as four digit year - two digit month - two digit day

jQuery does not use `yyyy` for a four digit year.

[jQuery format date options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qFxAH/)